# php google oauth issue

Tags: php, oauth

all. an issue about google oauth, the output url always return
     signature_invalid . I have no idea.

```
<?php
$url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?";

$scope ="scope=".urlencode(sprintf("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/%s/settings",urlencode("test@gmail.com")));
$oauth_consumer_key="&oauth_consumer_key=anonymous";
$oauth_nonce="&oauth_nonce=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
$oauth_signature_method=sprintf("&oauth_signature_method=%s","HMAC-SHA1");
$oauth_timestamp=sprintf("&oauth_timestamp=%s",time());
$oauth_signature="&oauth_signature=";


$base_string = $scope.$oauth_consumer_key.$oauth_nonce.$oauth_signature_method.$oauth_timestamp;

$call=$url.$base_string;

$call=$call.$oauth_signature.base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1",urlencode($base_string),"anonymous",true));

echo $call."\n";
/* file_get_contents($call); */


?>
```

I reference
     http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#rfc.section.9.1.1 and
     http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#RequestToken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,I find some people's answer.

at [PHP Oauth signature_invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515284/php-oauth-signature-invalid)

I can get the correct result. but need to check where is wrong in my code.